# TextView in android not wrapping the text to nextline

Tags: android, textview

Hi In my app I have a registration form in which both textview and edittext both face next to each other when I'm setting the large text to textview its not wrapping the text to next line.

Below is what I have tried.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="#336633"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:padding="8dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="FirstName"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="LastName"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pledged that I will Ride"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is the textview which has *pledge that I will ride*?

Comment: Fix width of textview. So, it will automatic wrap text to the next line.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I have edited the question please check it.

Comment: @Bhoomika I fear your trick wont work.

Comment: @Bhoomika its not working.

Comment: put your text view outside of your linear layout

Comment: @Bhoomika its now going in a new line.I need the textview to be continued after edittext.

Comment: because of text size it will go in next line. If you are comfirtable with small text then you can use small text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move the text inside a `TextView` to next line the way you want. If the text inside it is moved to next line, it will start the next line from the location it is located at (What you are experiencing here).

Best solution would be to put the last `TextView` outside of the `LinearLayout`.

Move

```
...
...
...
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="pledged that I"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="will Ride"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

outside the inner `LinearLayout`

Comment: its now going in a new line.I need the textview to be continued after edittext

Comment: It would go to new line -> whole text in that text view. It's different matter you don't want to move it below completely.

Comment: Why don't you use one more text view and put that one outside the inner linear layout.

Comment: yes I dont want the entire line to be moving to new line.

Comment: my plan is to design it according to the width of the screen it should wrap and split into the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,use `weightSum`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="#336633"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="I"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.33"
            android:hint="FirstName" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.33"
            android:hint="LastName" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="pledged that I will Ride"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add -- android:gravity="center"

Comment: I'm setting the large text to textview its not wrapping the text to next line what does this mean here. i have just added weightSum for proper display.

Comment: can you please explain more on it. @ShivLeela

Comment: large text in the sense pledged that i will ride.

Comment: you want "WILL RIDE" in next line under firstname text ? @ShivLeela

Comment: To make it happen you have to bring whole last textview to nextline under firstname and wrap that in single linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for solution where text will be wrapped around your EditText.

https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

Answer (score -1):

If you reduce the ems of text then it can help you.

for e.g. `android:ems="(size)"`

Note: size must be in pixels.